# Why isn't the mutex being aquired?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I have been looking into all of the different syncronization primitives available in the WinAPI, but have been struggling with what should have been something simple. Why doesn't the following code work?

```
class MultiThreadedCounter
{
private:
    int count; HANDLE hMutex;

public:
    void IncrementCounter()
    {
        if (count == 0)
            hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
        count++;
    }

    void DecrementCounter()
    {
        count--;
        if (count == 0)
            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }

    void WaitForCounterToReachZero()
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hMutex);
    }
};
MultiThreadedCounter extractionsInProgressCounter;
```

It's definitely getting called in the right order. First, `IncrementCounter()` is called by the main thread before the async task (here, a thread sleep). Then the main thread calls `WaitForCounterToReachZero()`. Finally, the background thread calls `DecrementCounter()` when it has completed its work, which should allow the main thread to proceed.

However, `WaitForSingleObject` is not waiting. It returns immediately, with `WAIT_OBJECT_0`. Why is it doing that? It's almost like the mutex was never initially aquired. However, in the call to `CreateMutex`, I set `bInitialOwner` to `TRUE`, which is why I don't understand why it doesn't seem to have been aquired. I guess I have misunderstood something.

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

OK, so to test, I changed `IncrementCounter()` to:

```
void IncrementCounter()
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
        DWORD var1 = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        DWORD var2 = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    }
    count++;
}
```

That really, really should have deadlocked it, but no, both calls to `WaitForSingleObject` returned immediately with `var1` and `var2` both equal to 0 (which according to the headers is WAIT_OBJECT_0).

The call to `CreateMutex` can't be working, can it? Yet `hMutex` gets set to a sensible value and `GetLastError()` remains at 0. So confused...

EDIT 2: Thank you all for your help. I never got this to work, however, I now realise that I was doing this the wrong way anyway. So I switched everything over to an Event, at which point it worked, then added a few conditionals to deal with out of order increments & decrements, then a critical section to protect the count variable. And it works :)

```
class MultiThreadedCounter
{
private:
int count; HANDLE hEvent; CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;

public:
void IncrementCounter()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    if (count == 0)
        ResetEvent(hEvent);
    count++;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
}

void DecrementCounter()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    if (count > 0)
        count--;
    if (count == 0)
        SetEvent(hEvent);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
}

void WaitForCounterToReachZero()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
}

MultiThreadedCounter()
{
    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
    InitializeCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    count = 0;
}

~MultiThreadedCounter()
{
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
}
};
```

Comment: I don't know much about winapi, but what happens when WaitForSingleObject is called before IncrementCounter is called? in what state will hMutex be and will that function be able to cope with it?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are sharing the object between the threads? Are you sure, they access the same object and not two different ones?

Comment: @ogni42: I'll try to edit it into the question in a minute, however, I'm pretty sure that they definitely are the same object. `MultiThreadedCounter extractionsInProgressCounter;` is outside of any function, and all functions use `extractionsInProgressCounter`, which isn't redefined anywhere. And I'm almost certain it's the same object, because when `WaitForSingleObject` is called, `count` is set to 1, and `hMutex` is set to (most recent run) 0xE8. So the initialisation must have gone reasonably well.

Comment: A mutex is, in any case, the wrong synchro primitive to use for this purpose.  Use a ManualResetEvent for the wait and use the mutex, (create in ctor!), to protect the count inc/dec - both IncrementCounter() and DecrementCounter() should be waiting for the mutex, inc/dec, release the mutex.

Comment: ..or use a CritcalSection instead of the mutex.  Either way, the inc/dec should be surrounded by Acquire/Release calls, and you need another synchro, eg. MRE, for the waiing thread to, well, wait on.

Comment: A semaphore may be a better choice.  It is already a type of waitable counter, an it can be incremented/decremented across thread boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show a constructor for `MultiThreadedCounter`.  Without this, there is no place to initialise `count` to 0, meaning that the first call to `IncrementCounter` almost certainly won't call `CreateMutex`

Your constructor should look something like

```
MultiThreadedCounter()
    : count(0)
    , hMutex(NULL)
{
}
```

As an aside, if you need a lock that is used between threads in a single process, you could consider using a [critical section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: That is a good point - I am using the default constructor only. However, I can put a breakpoint on the `CreateMutex` line, and it definitely gets hit. Additionally, the handle gets set to a sensible value, and remains sensible until passed into `WaitForSingleObject`. I can confirm using breakpoints that `count == 1` at that point, and that `DecrementCounter()` definitely hasn't been called at that point either. Thank you for your help.